# How will flashloans recover funds if the borrower makes a loss?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, flash-loans

I was studying flash loans recently which can be used for trading purposes. If we go through the smart contract code needed for the flash loans we need to repay the cost to the lender in 1 transaction only. Before that we can do what we want, we can make a trade and may also get loss in the trade but the trade has happened and now I have $1 less (for example) than the borrowed amount. I know the lender's smart contract calls my contract automatically to get funds, if funds are low then they revert the transaction. So does reverting the transaction will also revert my trade to get back the money?

Comment: yes. everything is reverted so your only loss will be paying for gas

Comment: @sola24 so then I have pay the gas fee two times? One time before and one while reverting it ?

Comment: no. I mean if it reverts you don't get gas refunded, so you'll lose that, but that's all

Comment: @sola24 I mean do I have to pay gas fee twice ? One time ETH - > DAI (for eg) and one time while reverting the txn ?

Comment: no. you just pay gas for computation done up to the point it's reverted. It's not like going through the same process again in reverse. More like a reset.